# Run a command when responding to an event

Tags: wpf, xaml, events, mvvm, command

Basically, I am trying to respond to an event raised by a WPF control, but instead of using code-behind, run a command (an ICommand) instead.

I have a Window called CouponView and a UserControl called SingleBetView. I have a ViewModel called CouponViewModel which is the DataContext of CouponView, and a ViewModel called BetsViewModel which is the DataContext of SingleBetView. I am adding SingleBetView to CouponView and setting it's DataContext like this:

```
<View:SingleBetView DataContext="{Binding Path=BetsViewModel}" />
```

SingleBetView contains a DataGrid, I want to respond to the KeyDown event of this grid. I have created a Command class called DownArrowRepeatsStakesCommand, and placed an instance of this inside BetsViewModel like this:

```
public DownArrowRepeatsStakesCommand DownArrowRepeatsStakesCommand { get; set; }
```

I then instantiate this inside the constructor of BetsViewModel like so:

```
DownArrowRepeatsStakesCommand = new DownArrowRepeatsStakesCommand(_bets); //_bets is an observable collection, my DataGridView is bound to this ObservableCollection and when the KeyDown is pressed, I want to update various elements
```

I know that I can link a button to my Command easily enough, by simply binding it to the instance in the ViewModel like so:

```
Command="{Binding DownArrowRepeatsStakesCommand}"
```

But the same doesn't seem to work for responding to events:

```
KeyDown="{Binding DownArrowRepeatsStakesCommand}
```

I get the following runtime error:

```
A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'AddKeyDownHandler' property of type 'DataGrid'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.
```

I tried Reed's suggestion of using MVVM light (which I added via NuGet) and the steps found [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2009/11/05/mvvm-light-toolkit-v3-alpha-2-eventtocommand-behavior.aspx), great in theory but I got the below error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4,
>   PublicKeyToken=1673db7d5906b0ad' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Here is the XAML I added to the DataGrid:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyUp">
        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DownArrowRepeatsStakesCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Here is a screenshot (no inner exception):

[image: Screenshot]

I also get the following two warnings:

- Cannot add instance of type 'EventTrigger' to a collection of type 'TriggerCollection'. Only items of type 'T' are allowed.
- A value of type 'EventTrigger' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'TriggerCollection'.

Slightly baffled!

Is there any way to do what I am trying to do in a Command, or it code-behind the only option?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported in WPF directly.  You need some extra "glue" like [MVVM Light's EventToCommand](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2009/11/05/mvvm-light-toolkit-v3-alpha-2-eventtocommand-behavior.aspx) implementation, which allows you to take any event and map it to an `ICommand` in the ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks, this looks great in theory but didn't work out so well in practice, I've updated my question with what went wrong, maybe you might see something I don't.